# In python how to count occurance of elements in list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list;

```
['html', 'header', 'title', 'body', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'ul', 'li', 'li', 'li']
```

i want to print items having occurrence three or more.

output should be `'li'` and `'div'`

Can anyone help me python code to do this.

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: wat u already tried?

Comment: Counting the occurance of an element is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python. The rest is basic logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> l = ['html', 'header', 'title', 'body', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'ul', 'li', 'li', 'li']
>>> [item for item, cnt in Counter(l).items() if cnt > 2]
['li', 'div']
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using `Counter`,

```
In [198]: e = ['html', 'header', 'title', 'body', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'ul', 'li', 'li', 'li']
In [199]: list(set([v for v in e if e.count(v)>=3]))
Out[199]: ['li', 'div']
```

(Only for short lists as it isn't too efficient).

Comment: its better to use set for `e` : `>>> [v for v in set(e) if e.count(v)>=3]
['li', 'div']`

Comment: @xnx, this is quadratic as opposed to a linear solution using Counter

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham. True, as noted in my answer. Whether this makes a difference in practice depends on the length of the tag list, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections` module.

`Counter` method will add all items from list `l` as key and value is their counts.
So you can find keys according their counts by your logic.

Code:

```
from collections import Counter

l = ['html', 'header', 'title', 'body', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'ul', 'li', 'li', 'li']

c = Counter(l)
for key, count in c.items():
    print("[{}] - {}".format(key, count))
```

Output:

```
[body] - 1
[ul] - 1
[title] - 1
[li] - 3
[header] - 1
[html] - 1
[div] - 5
```

Documentation for this module https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

```
L = ['html', 'header', 'title', 'body', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'ul', 'li', 'li', 'li']

result = []

for i in range(len(L)):

    if L.count(L[i]) >= 3 and L[i] not in result:
        result.append(L[i])

print result
```

Output

```
['div', 'li']
```